# How to resolve errors when deploying rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My first time ever deploying a rails app to heroku and I can't get it to work.

I've followed the directions here:

https://www.codecademy.com/articles/deploy-rails-to-heroku

```
remote:        Bundle completed (206.01s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.15.3-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.16.0
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Rails couldn't infer whether you are using multiple databases from your database.yml and can't generate the tasks for the non-primary databases. If you'd like to use this feature, please simplify your ERB.
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        YAML syntax error occurred while parsing /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/config/database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 8 column 1
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:246:in `rescue in database_configuration'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:221:in `database_configuration'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in on_load'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `on_load'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:198:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:
remote:        Caused by:
remote:        Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 8 column 1
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:228:in `database_configuration'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in on_load'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `on_load'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:198:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_75338afd2107b4ab61f0bd3f16d859f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to politiscale-01.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/politiscale-01.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/politiscale-01.git'
```

Also here's my relevant bit from my gem file:

```
   gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
   gem 'pg', '0.18.1', group: :production
```

And my datbase.yml file:

```
# SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported.
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

#default: &default
 # adapter: sqlite3
#  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
#  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

 production:
   <<: *default
   adapter: postgresql
   database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Ya'll want to do your thing and tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: your `production` section is indented 1 space, is that on purpose or a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: also, you have adapter postgresql but an sqlite3 database, that doesn't make sense, you can't use sqlite in heroku, you have to use the postgres add on

Comment: follow the official guide to configure the database https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6

Answer (score 0):

in your database.yml file change this line-

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

......
```

it will be better if you keep your Gemfile like this-

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

and deploy again on heroku